# Creating Options menu in Android

Tags: android, options-menu, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to create options menu in my Android program.  I am using the following code to inflate options menu :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);   
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
        return true;
   }
```

And my xml code is :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/Option1"
    android:title="Option1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/Option2"
    android:title="Option2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/Option3"
    android:title="Option3"/>
</menu>
```

But with this code i am not able to show the options menu in my screen.

Also, i am using the code

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to make the activity as full screen view.  Does this code creates problem in inflating the menu?

Thanks in advance,

Timson

Comment: This is for which Android Version?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267030/oncreateoptionsmenu-is-never-called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the line `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` from your onCreateOptionMenu. You are actually already providing the menu before inflating it.

Comment: I tried without super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu).  but still am not getting the menu. Is it a problem with the full screen view?

Comment: no. it shouldn't be a problem with full screen. Clean your project and then run

Comment: I given a Log inside the onCreateOptionsMenu method. But log is not coming in the console.  So can i assume that @Override  is not working?

Comment: are you overriding this in your activity? just thought to confirm :)

Comment: yes. Am overriding it :) and I am using ActivityGroup in my program. Does this create any issue with menu?

Comment: it should work in ActivityGroup too. If you are using Activites to add inside your activitygroup then add this code to your activities rather than to group

Comment: hmmm try adding to ActivityGroup and see, because i just tested it doing on one of my own ActivityGroup and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Options menu shows up by pressing the Options Menu button at the bottom of the phone

Comment: Android version is 2.2.  I am pressing the options menu at the bottom.  But still the code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

as that will return a value before your code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code without "super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); " working perfectly for me..