# How to add "info" and "help" tab to my Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add a "Info" and "Help" buttons when clicking on "Settings" to my application,How?
I read some similar questions but I couldn't understand, I am not that expert in programing but I will do my best.

Heres a screen shot for what I am trying to do :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a standard options menu for android.  [Here is the doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) for how to set that up.  Note that if you want them there all the time, you could simply use a linear layout, with two image buttons

Comment: I couldn't implement it , actually I did not now how to start , I tried some codes form other questions but I am confused how to do it . Is there any chance to guide me in step by step how to create an options menu , I am really confused .

Comment: I got a good answer by @Deepanker Chaudhary , at this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267030/oncreateoptionsmenu-is-never-called) , Thnks Deepanker.