# Options menu persists in the second activity

Tags: android

After clicking a button to open a new Activity using this method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_comunidades01);
```

The second Activity still display the same menu as the previous one.

I have already readed serval methods to fix it as the one related in here:

[Android: How to enable/disable option menu item on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440601/android-how-to-enable-disable-option-menu-item-on-button-click)

But I discovered that the methods to intialize and create the menu are never called. I even try to follow this other link without success:

[onCreateOptionsMenu is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267030/oncreateoptionsmenu-is-never-called)

I even deleted all the items in the menu.xml for this activity but still displaying the previous activity options.

I also clarify I am using android 4.4 as target API but level 10 as a minimum one since some devices that will be used are running android 2.3.

My second Activity is like this:

```
  public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_SecondActivity);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        System.out.println("EN ON PREPARE OPTIONS MENU");
        (menu.findItem(R.id.sincronizar)).setEnabled(false);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        System.out.println("EN ON CREATE OPTIONS MENU");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.SecondActivity, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start second activity use this:

```
Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish(); //if you want to close FirstActivity after showing SecondActivity
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> After clicking a button to open a new Activity using this method:
>
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_comunidades01)

This is not how you open another activity!
This way you only change the *content* of the current activity, nothing else.

Use [`Activity.startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) or [`Activity.startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) to start another activity.