# Unable to Exit App Using Drawer Menu "Exit" Option in Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, drawerlayout

**Description:**

I am developing an Android app, and I have encountered an issue with the "Exit" option in the drawer menu. When I click on the "Exit" option, nothing happens, and the app doesn't quit. I have implemented several Log.d statements to debug the problem.

Here is the code for my `WelcomeActivity`:

```
package com.enetapplications.songtracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        Log.d("WelcomeActivity", "WA: onCreate method (line 23)");
        Log.d("ActivityTracker", "WelcomeActivity is created");

        // Get references to the TextViews
        TextView welcomeText = findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
        TextView userNameText = findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
        TextView userEmailText = findViewById(R.id.userEmailText);
        TextView userIdText = findViewById(R.id.userIdText);

        // Retrieve user data from intent extras
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
        String userEmail = intent.getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");
        int userId = intent.getIntExtra("USER_ID", -1); // Use "USER_ID" as the key name

        // Set the values in TextViews
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + userName);
        userNameText.setText("User Name: " + userName);
        userEmailText.setText("Email: " + userEmail);
        userIdText.setText("User ID: " + userId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer_menu, menu);
        Log.d("WelcomeActivity", "WA: Menu created (line 47)");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("WelcomeActivity", "WA: just entering onOptionsItemSelected (line 52)");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Handle other menu items if any

            case R.id.menu_item_exit:
                // Add code here to perform logout or cleanup tasks if needed
                Log.d("WelcomeActivity", "WA: Exit menu item clicked");
                finish(); // This will close the app
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

For the `drawer_menu.xml` file, here is the relevant section where I have defined the "Exit" option:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- Header: About -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_about_header"
        android:title="About"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <!-- About Menu Group -->
    <group android:id="@+id/group_about">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_app_information"
            android:title="App Information" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_credits"
            android:title="Credits" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_exit"
            android:title="Exit" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I am trying to get the "Exit" option to quit however nothing happens when I click on the "Exit" in the `drawer_menu`.  I have placed numerous `Log.d` tags and know when I have arrived at the `WelcomeActivity` page however only the `Log.d` in the `onCreate` method is reached.  No errors are thrown and app seems to run ok, however I cannot figure out why the "Exit" is not working.

Thank you advance for any assistance you may provide!

best,
Brian

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. Do _any_ of the options work, or just "exit" fails? (BTW, "exit" is kinda pointless in Android - that's what the back button is for). What happens if you remove the "group"?

Comment: Thanks @dominicoder - appreciate the information/feedback!  None of the other  menu options are coded, thought I'd start with something simple and build from there thus the 'exit' strategy :)  Good idea to try outside of the `group` tag but still the same output.  None of the `Log.d` statements are reflected within Logcat output for `WelcomeActivity.java`

Comment: "None of the Log.d statements are reflected within Logcat output for WelcomeActivity.java" - but you see the "Exit" button show? So you can click it, yes? So the log statement `Log.d("WelcomeActivity", "WA: Menu created (line 47)");` should be printing.

Comment: @dominicoder correct in that the `Log.d` messages *should* be displayed however they are not.  On the `WelcomeActivity` page there are multiple 'Log.d` statements - in methods `onCreate`, `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`.  It is only the `Log.d` in `onCreate` (`WelcomeActivity` page) which displays, thus it would seem that the app never reaches those two other methods...

Comment: How do you run the app - a pyshical device or an emuletor? Try to set a breakpoint in the non working Log commands and run the app in debug mode - does the program reaches the non-working statements?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267030/oncreateoptionsmenu-is-never-called

Comment: Thanks again @dominicoder, checking that link out however before I was testing out this and I was able to get the method to run.  In the `item` added an `onClick`, so (not sure how this will render here..) ```        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_exit"
            android:title="Exit"
            android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected"/>``` and this called the method and ran the associated code.  So is the answer adding an `onClick` or is that a work-around.  Also it seems that the `onCreateOptionsMenu` is never called as the `Log.d` is never hit - ?

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu` would have to be called if the menu is visible and you can click on "Exit". Are you perhaps inflating the menu elsewhere as well, like in a fragment?

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu` is not being inflated from `WelcomeActivity` - as I removed the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and ran the app and menu behaved exactly as before, so it is being run somewhere in the inheritance chain or as you suggest, some fragment (not by me). Btw with the addition of onClick in the `item` seems to have solved the original problem about executing the code on button click to 'exit' - unless you have other input I can close this and much appreciation for feedback @dominicoder which definitely helped move this case forward!